# Django Many to Many relationship Query Filter

Tags: python, django

```
class servers(models.Model):
hostname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
ip= models.CharField(max_length=100)
os= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class application(models.Model)
name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
URL= models.CharField(max_length=100)
servers= models.ManyToManyField(servers, blank = True, null=True)
```

current DB status

3 servers 2 with os as linux and 1 with os as windows

2 applications

Requirement : application can have many servers and each server can be part of many applications also
Need support to create filter only those applications whose os is windows. I tried below but it is returning all three servers.

```
def viewapp(request,pk)
criterion1 = Q(id=pk)
criterion2 = Q(servers__os__startswith="windows")
prodlist = application.objects.filter(criterion1 & criterion2)
```

Comment: You mean when you access `myapplication.servers.all()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the many-to-many field as well with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def viewapp(request,pk):
    prodlist = application.objects.filter(
        id=pk, servers__os__startswith='windows'
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('servers', Server.objects.filter(os__startswith='windows'))
    )
```

since you here work with one object however, it is better to work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def viewapp(request, pk):
    prod = get_object_or_404(
        application.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('servers', Server.objects.filter(os__startswith='windows')
        ),
        pk=pk
    )
```

Here `prod` is a single `application` *object*, not a `QuerySet` of `application`s.

Comment: using your code , I am able to filter appropriate results . However the result is getting repeated multiple times when displaying in html template. My template code is 
{% for App in App%}

{% for server in App.servers.all %}
{{ server.os}}, {{ server.hostname}}

<br>
{% endfor %}

<br>
{% endfor %}

Comment: @Mir: but there is only one `application`, hence the `{% for App in App %}` makes not much sense.